# what's the best way to sort this NSArray of NSDictionary's with different keys but values of the same type

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am struggling to find a good way to sort an `NSArray` like this:

It's an array of `NSDictionary`s, and I am using it to keep track of appearance of each word in a long string. So it might look somewhat like this:

```
[{"hello", 5}, {"world", 10}, {"this", 1}, {"that", 3}]
```

Now I want to sort this `NSDictionary` by the value, so that it looks like this:

```
[{"world", 10}, {"hello", 5}, {"that", 3}, {"this", 1}]
```

I have looked at `NSSortDescriptor` and the `initWithKey` method for the sortDesciptors, but it requires the name of the keys to be the same, which doesn't apply to my case.

What do you suggest me use in this case? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your design doesn't seem to match your plan. The inner collections shouldn't be dictionaries here. You're not gaining anything by it, and in fact it's just getting in your way. Either make them two-element arrays, or make the outer collection a dictionary with the words as keys and drop the nesting altogether.

Comment: Does `NSDictionary` preserve order?

Comment: No, but you can get the keys sorted by the values whenever you like.

Comment: I see! Yeah I thought my structure of the data was kind of convoluted as well, I'll probably change that. Thanks!

Comment: Or, if you want to keep the inner dictionaries, you can use something like `@[@{@"word": @"hello", @"value": @5}, @"word": @"world", @"value": @10}, @"word": @"this", @"value": @1}, @"word": @"that", @"value": @3}]`.  Then, at least you can sort by the `value` key....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe not the most efficient way ever, but this will do

```
NSArray * d = @[@{@"world": @10}, @{@"hello": @5}, @{@"that": @3}, @{@"this": @1}];
[d sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary * obj1, NSDictionary * obj2) {
    NSNumber * v1 = obj1[[obj1 allKeys][0]];
    NSNumber * v2 = obj2[[obj2 allKeys][0]];
    return [v1 compare:v2];
}];
```

Anyway, the data organization is not very suitable for the task. Since the inner data structure is a dictionary, gathering the value is rather cumbersome. You may consider making the inner one an array.

Comment: Yeah I realized that. I will probably change the organization of the data. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Not bad at all. Although I think this case demands a redesign, I definitely like the fact that a code solution to the problem as literally stated will be here for searchers with a similar problem. I was reluctant to post my answer, in fact. Kudos.

Comment: @Josh thank you. I believe the case you're making about the data chosen by the OP is more than correct. My answer provides a "quick" solution to the problem as stated, but future searches will probably consider a redesign thank you yours. +1

Answer (score 3):

Your design doesn't seem to match your plan. The inner collections shouldn't be dictionaries here. You're not gaining anything by it, and in fact it's just getting in your way. Either make them two-element arrays, or make the outer collection a dictionary with the words as keys and drop the nesting altogether.